# Copying i value from arraylist to array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, processing

So I am making a program that needs to be overwrite value i from ArrayList to value i in array. For the life of me I cannot figure out what I should do. I've tried looking for similar problems here, but can't seem to find them. Obviously, my loop is very wrong as it is, as it is just overwriting the entire loop, but I can't figure it out. Any kind-hearted person want to help me?

BTW, I am using Java with Processing

```
Dot[] dots = new Dot[16];
ArrayList<Dot> extraDots = new ArrayList<Dot>();
```

Fill them with values and later ...

```
for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; ++i) {
    if (dots[i].timeRemain == 0 && !dotTouch)
    {
        //arrayCopy(extraDots, i, dots, i, 1);
        //this is basically what I want,  but from an arraylist to the array

        dots = extraDots.toArray(new Dot[i]); //So, so wrong, I know
        dotTouch = true;
    }
    dotTouch = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean

```
dots[i] = extraDots.get(i);
```

???

Comment: Yes, exactly. I knew it was simple, just not how simple. Wauw.

Comment: Apparently that wasn't quite it, as it now throws "Cannot invoke get(int) on the array type Dot[]"

Comment: you should call get on ArrayList (extraDots), not array of dots. To access Dot[], you simply call dot[i]. I strongly suggest you read basic java tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't get your problem..
simply you can do like below to copy from arraylist to array
why you are using dots[i].timeRemain and dotTouch. can you clarify??

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; ++i) {
            dots[i] = extraDots.get(i);
}
```